# CSS Background-size: contain without the image to scale up

Tags: css

i've got a fixed width/height Div which holds images as background.

I want them to fit in the div without overflow - this is the perfect situation for

`background-size: contain;`

But if the image is smaller than the Div, it is being scaled up. I dont want that.
What I am looking for is something like max-width and max-height for the background-image.

Here you can see a simple example (with random images) of my problem:
http://jsbin.com/uQevuna/1/edit

It is not possible to change the html code of the page.

Comment: Actually `cover` will scale but `contain` will make it fit. Can you post your code or create a fiddle?

Comment: I added one to the original post, sorry

Comment: that would be possible, but I was hoping for a more smart solution :)

Comment: @Hauke I thought as much ;) I am only asking because I genuinely done't think there's a pure CSS option. However I love it when I'm proved wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually can't be done with the `background-size`, because they keywords don't take the original image size into account.

[Here's an alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9NJY/3/) using `display: table-cell`

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
}
.wrap div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: We've got a new built of the website which has a semilar solution (at least not that background-image stuff) but we had to hotfix the older version. But thanks - this is obvious the most correct way to archieve such behaviour.